# Google slides add image binary to slide

Tags: java, image, google-drive-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I working on creating Google slides via java using service account. I'm able to:

- authenticate
- create drive and slide service
- create presentation and add empty slide

I'm struggling with adding image from binary. I can add image that is stored in some online image storage.
I have problem with adding image that is byte[].
I dig and I found that image must be uploaded to drive location and I'm able to do that.
The problem I have is with adding that image to the slide in presentation. I'm receiving:

```
`Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/1yUi4nMxjdOfI97jvJP9uG42LyT_5Kd4NN_M9S-B65CM:batchUpdate
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Invalid requests[0].createImage: There was a problem retrieving the image. The provided image should be publicly accessible, within size limit, and in supported formats.",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid requests[0].createImage: There was a problem retrieving the image. The provided image should be publicly accessible, within size limit, and in supported formats.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:439)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:525)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:576)
    at com.microstrategy.sdk.AddImageFromBinary.insertImageRequestIntoSlide(AddImageFromBinary.java:165)
    at com.microstrategy.sdk.AddImageFromBinary.main(AddImageFromBinary.java:119)Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/1yUi4nMxjdOfI97jvJP9uG42LyT_5Kd4NN_M9S-B65CM:batchUpdate
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Invalid requests[0].createImage: There was a problem retrieving the image. The provided image should be publicly accessible, within size limit, and in supported formats.",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid requests[0].createImage: There was a problem retrieving the image. The provided image should be publicly accessible, within size limit, and in supported formats.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:439)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:525)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:576)
    at com.microstrategy.sdk.AddImageFromBinary.insertImageRequestIntoSlide(AddImageFromBinary.java:165)
    at com.microstrategy.sdk.AddImageFromBinary.main(AddImageFromBinary.java:119)`
```

Service account has necessary access and it's owner of the png file that is created in drive location. Scope for credentials is set:
`private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, SlidesScopes.PRESENTATIONS, SlidesScopes.DRIVE_FILE);`

Here is code:

```
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/booking.json";

    private static final String GOOGLE_FOLDER_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    private static final String GOOGLE_SLIDES_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
InputStream in = AddImageFromBinary.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in).createScoped(SCOPES);
        System.out.println(credentials);

        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

        Slides slidesService = new Slides.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        // createFolder(service, "aaa");
        String presentationName = "Test-presentation-10";
        Presentation presentation = createGooglePresentation(slidesService, presentationName);
        String presentationId = presentation.getPresentationId();
        System.out.println("presentationId: " + presentationId);
        //IMPORTANT to get presentation obj. again
        presentation = getPresentation(slidesService, presentationId);
        presentationId = presentation.getPresentationId();
        System.out.println("new presentationId: " + presentationId);
        
        if (presentation.getSlides() != null && !presentation.getSlides().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("removing first slide");
            String firstSlideId = presentation.getSlides().get(0).getObjectId();

            deleteFirstSlide(slidesService, presentationId, firstSlideId);
            //presentation = getPresentation(slidesService, presentationId);
        }
        String slideId = createSlide(slidesService, presentationId);
        System.out.println("Slide ID: " + slideId);
        
        byte[] pictureData = getImageFromPDF(fullExportData);
        
        // Upload the image to Google Drive and get the file ID
        String imageFileId = uploadImageToDrive(service, pictureData);
        
        
        getPermissions(service, imageFileId);
        
        String imageUrl = getImageUrl(service, imageFileId);
        //String imageUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1SGtAp_KMmPHuts1HHap0TiY8CsKWJGeT";
        
        //CreateImageRequest imageRequest = createImageRequest(imageUrl);

        // Insert the image request into the slide
        insertImageRequestIntoSlide(slidesService, presentationId, slideId, imageUrl);
        
        if (!presentationId.isEmpty()) {
            uploadGoogleSlides(service, presentationId, presentationName);
            System.out.println("Upload success...");
        }
}

private static Presentation createGooglePresentation(Slides slidesService, String title) throws Exception {

        Presentation presentation = null;
        try {

            // Creates a blank presentation with a specified title.
            presentation = new Presentation().setTitle(title);

            presentation = slidesService
                    .presentations()
                    .create(presentation)
                    .setFields("presentationId")
                    .execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return presentation;

    }

public static Presentation getPresentation(Slides slidesService, String presentationId) throws IOException {
        return slidesService.presentations().get(presentationId).execute();
    }

public static String createSlide(Slides service, String presentationId) throws IOException {

        // Add a slide at index 1 using the predefined "TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS" layout
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        String slideId = null;
        BatchUpdatePresentationResponse response = null;
        try {
            requests.add(new Request().setCreateSlide(new CreateSlideRequest()
            
            ));

            BatchUpdatePresentationRequest body = new BatchUpdatePresentationRequest().setRequests(requests);
            response = service.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId, body).execute();
            CreateSlideResponse createSlideResponse = response.getReplies().get(0).getCreateSlide();
            // Prints the slide id.
            slideId = createSlideResponse.getObjectId();
            System.out.println("Created slide with ID: " + slideId);
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();
            if (error.getCode() == 400) {
                System.out.printf(" Id '%s' should be unique among all pages and page elements.\n", presentationId);
            } else if (error.getCode() == 404) {
                System.out.printf("Presentation not found with id '%s'.\n", presentationId);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return slideId;
    }

private static String uploadImageToDrive(Drive service, byte[] imageBytes) throws IOException {
        
        File fileMetadata = new File()
                .setName("image.png")
                .setMimeType("image/png")
                .setParents(Collections.singletonList(ROOT_FOLDER));

        ByteArrayContent mediaContent = new ByteArrayContent("image/png", imageBytes);

        File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                //.setFields("id")
                .setFields("id , parents")
                .execute();

        return file.getId();
    }

`private static String getImageUrl(Drive service, String imageId) {
        try {
            // Use the Drive service to retrieve information about the file
            File file = service.files().get(imageId).setFields("webContentLink").execute();
            
            
                // The webContentLink provides the URL to download the file (image)
                String imageUrl = file.getWebContentLink();
                System.out.println("Image URL: " + imageUrl);
                return imageUrl;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }`

`private static void insertImageRequestIntoSlide(Slides slidesService, String presentationId, String slideId, String imageUrl) throws IOException {
        
        
        CreateImageRequest createImageRequest = new CreateImageRequest()
                .setObjectId("myImage")
                .setUrl(imageUrl)
                .setElementProperties(new PageElementProperties()
                        .setPageObjectId(slideId)
                        .setSize(new Size()
                                .setHeight(new Dimension()
                                        .setMagnitude(300.0)
                                        .setUnit("PT"))
                                .setWidth(new Dimension()
                                        .setMagnitude(400.0)
                                        .setUnit("PT")))
                        .setTransform(new AffineTransform()
                                .setScaleX(1.0)
                                .setScaleY(1.0)
                                .setTranslateX(50.0)
                                .setTranslateY(50.0)));

        Request imageRequest = new Request().setCreateImage(createImageRequest);

        BatchUpdatePresentationRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdatePresentationRequest()
                .setRequests(Collections.singletonList(imageRequest));

        slidesService.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId, batchUpdateRequest).execute();

    }`
`
private static String uploadGoogleSlides(Drive service, String presentationId, String title) throws IOException {

        String presentationCopyId = null;
        try {
            // Copies an existing presentation using specified presentation title.
            File copyMetadata = new File()
                    .setName(title)
                    .setParents(Collections.singletonList(ROOT_FOLDER));

            File presentationCopyFile = service.files().copy(presentationId, copyMetadata).setFields("id , parents")
                    .execute();

            presentationCopyId = presentationCopyFile.getId();
            // Prints the new copied presentation id.
            System.out.println("New copied presentation id " + presentationCopyId);
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();
            if (error.getCode() == 404) {
                System.out.printf("Presentation not found with id '%s'.\n", presentationId);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return presentationCopyId;
    }
`
```